# Is it possible to use SQLite as a client-server database?

Tags: sqlite

Are there any techniques or tools to work with SQLite on a medium size/traffic/concurrency DB environment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database and it is not intended to be used as a client/server DB. If you really want to, you can use [SQLitening](http://www.sqlitening.com/).

## What SQLitening is

> SQLitening is a client/server implementation of the very popular SQLite database.
>
> SQLitening is a programmer's library in standard Win32 DLL form. It is installed as a standard Windows Service. In addition to client/server mode, the library allows the programmer to also access SQLite databases in local mode. In either mode (local or client/server), the database is extremely fast and robust.
>    -- Source: http://www.planetsquires.com/sqlite_client_server.htm

Answer (score 27):

As stated before sqlite is not a client-server application and it is not built for highly concurrent operations.

Nevertheless you can "make it client-server", if you use ssh.

```
ssh user@host sqlite3 databasefile select * from table
```

works.

Comment: Is this considered "client-server" because you've encrypted the connection?

Comment: No, it is just because of a network between the machine which hosts the db and the machine accessing the db.

Comment: This will not work if the shell expands `*` to a list of all files in the current folder, which it does.

Comment: I think you could wrap the SQL statement in quotes

Answer (score 8):

No, SQLite doesn't present a network endpoint - it is only accessible via the filesystem. It *does* support concurrent access from multiple processes on the same machine but at a very coarse-grained level (DML locks an entire table). So you could have a dozen Apache httpd processes all with a SQLite database on the local disk open, all doing `SELECT`s and it would work just fine. But really, it's the wrong tool for the job - I'd use [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) in this scenario.